# How to repeat loop until a valid answer is given?

Tags: python, while-loop

So I coded a function that takes the value of a batteries variable. I want it to do something if the value is "yes" or "no". If the value is none of these answers, I want it to to ask it again for an indefinite amount of times. Here is my code in case my description was bad.

```
def batterie_answer():
    batteries = raw_input("yes or no > ").lower()
    print batteries
    while True:
        if batteries != "yes" or batteries != "no":
            print "Please respond yes or no"
            raw_input("> ")
            continue
        elif batteries == "yes":
            print "batteries taken!"
            items["batteries"] = 1
            break
        elif batteries == "no":
            print "Probably a wise choice. Save some space!"
            break

batterie_answer()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/1540468

Comment: Your second use of `raw_input` should be identical to your first use: use lower and assign to batteries (aside: `answer` is probably a better variable name than `batteries`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the assignment to inside the `while` loop or add another assignment. You also need to change the `or` to an `and`. You would also need to remove the extra `raw_input` line that does not assign the value to the `batteries` variable.

```
def batterie_answer():
    while True:
        batteries = raw_input("yes or no > ").lower()
        print batteries
        if batteries != "yes" and batteries != "no":
            print "Please respond yes or no"
            continue
        elif batteries == "yes":
            print "batteries taken!"
            items["batteries"] = 1
            break
        elif batteries == "no":
            print "Probably a wise choice. Save some space!"
            break

batterie_answer()
```

Comment: Hey I'm a noobie in coding, so that's why I ask easy questions, but can you explain to me why I have to put batteries assignement line in the while loop and why I have to put an and instead of an or.

Comment: If you don't put the assignment line inside the while loop, then the value of the variable never changes while you're in the loop, which means you can never get out of it.

Comment: And the reason you have to use `and` rather than `or` is that with `or`, that expression is always true. If `batteries` is equal to `yes` then it is not equal to `no` so the second part is true, and vice versa. Therefore at least one branch of the `or` is always true and that makes the whole thing true.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop doesn't include the original `raw_input()` command, so it's never going to ask for input after the first iteration. Instead, it will only ever print out the answer over and over again.

Move the `while True` up a few lines so that it encompasses the `raw_input()` command.

Comment: The while loop does have a `raw_input` line. Fixing that line would probably be more instructive to the OP than just ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your if statement. It doesn't matter what value is given, the condition will always equate to true and it will ask again for a value. For example, if the value was "yes" then the condition would be `(false or true)` which equates to true, if the value was "no" then it would be `(true or false)` which also equates to true, if the value was something like "asdf" then it would be `(true or true)` which also equates to true.

to fix this change the "or" operator to an "and" operator.

```
if batteries != "yes" and batteries != "no":
```